# XHTML Strict: br tag inside p tag

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I get lots of [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.webwave.com/terms&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) because of <br /> inside <p>. If I remove the br tags then it works fine.

Why is it creating a problem?

Comment: I can't get link to work. <br /> should work fine. Are you sure that your <br> is terminated like this <br /> ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not that the `br` is inside the `p`, but rather you're not ending the `br` with the `/` character. You have `<br>` in the code, when it should be `<br/>`. Which is why the validation error is "end tag for "br" omitted", it's telling you that you've not ended the tag correctly with a /.

Note that in HTML4 it's not required to close the `br` tag with a final slash, but in XHTML it is required as it's a singleton tag.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the answer you gave a few seconds earlier than me.

Comment: any idea if IE6 will get confused by <br/> or any other browsers?